# How to use native C++ libraries in Mono for Android (monodroid) and MonoTouch

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I am interested in using Mono for Android and MonoTouch to build mobile applications that can make use of a large number of C++ native libraries that I have. Can I get some specific instructions on how to call methods or incorporate the code into my final mobile app on iOS or Android?

I have looked at the Xamarin documentation online it is pretty cryptic to me as someone who is new to programming mobile apps ([Mono for Android](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries) and [MonoTouch](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linking_native_libraries)). In the case of building a monodroid app in Visual Studio (which is what I am most familiar with), what are specific steps I need to call a native function from my MonoDroid program. For the C libraries, I can compile in either .DLL (dynamic) or .LIB (static) form. I am also under the impression that dynamic libraries cannot be used for mobile apps.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think you can.  I could very well be wrong about this as I haven't done anything particularly low-level/crazy with MonoDroid and I haven't used MonoTouch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to bind C++ libraries using P/Invokes, but this is not a particularly nice way (since you will be binding to the mangled function names, which are quite unintelligible and will likely change between compilers/OSes).

The recommended way of accessing C++ libraries is to create a C API and use P/Invoke (you can find a lot of information about how to do P/Invoking on the web, here is one place to start: http://mono-project.com/Dllimport).

Also, for MonoTouch it is not possible to use dynamic libraries (this is an Apple restriction), you have to use static libraries. I do not know if there are any restrictions like this for Mono for Android.

Answer (score 5):

The best choice is to use Swig to create a binding for your C++ library that you can access from C#.

Here is a description:

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html

Answer (score 3):

Cxxi doesn't work with monotouch. As I ran to this same issue last week, I blogged about how to get SWIG works for monotouch:

http://blog.reblochon.org/2013/01/c-bindings-for-monotouch-using-swig.html

Answer (score 2):

This blog post from Miguel is an interesting read on the topic.

[CXXI: Bridging the C++ and C# worlds.](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html)

I do not know if CXXI is available a this time, but it is a project to keep an eye on and support.